# Why my cursor disappears when I target error(red line)?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, popup, mouse

I have problem with my error-popup.
I don't know exactly when this error started too. I guess it started since 2weeks ago.

When I want to know why it has error(red line),
I target error line but It doesn't display tool-tip box.
Alt+Enter is working, but only errors on tool-tip.

I want to know why it occurs red line and fix it, but I have no idea.
Error popup pops often, and It disappear soon.

I even thought about whether I had a 'Hand Tremor', but I don't.
I tested with tablet pen too.

I captured my test project.
Can sombody help me?

[Captured video link] https://youtu.be/yAL64unssDE

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yAL64unssDE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: If the error isn't visible in the editor by the tooltip, then press the build/compile button and check the output.

Comment: 0-<-< Is it doesn't have way to fix tooltip?

Comment: It's possibly just a bug in Android Studio.